# "this[key]" on a for() in javacscript with prototype

Tags: javascript, prototype-programming

I've a JS error on the 5th line of this script (var el = this[key];). It works on FF, Chrome, Safari but not on IE. Someone can help me ?

```
Object.prototype.between = function( value )
{
    var value = parseFloat(value);
    for (key in this) {         
        var el = this[key];
        var v = key.split('-');         

        var min = parseFloat(v[0]);
        var max = parseFloat(v[1]);

        if (value >= min && value < max) { return el; }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Thanks for advance

Comment: What is the error? Just as a side note, you might be better off with a separate function than extending `Object.prototype` for several reasons.

Comment: 1) You should **not** be extending the `Object.prototype`. 2) You should be declaring `key` before you use it (`for (var key in this)`). 3) You should most likely be checking for `this.hasOwnProperty(key)` in your loop. The 3rd recommendation will *most likely* fix your error.

Comment: I've tried your solution, it seems better but now, i've an error with Jquery on line 3539 : "if ( (match = Expr.leftMatch[ type ].exec( expr )) != null && match[2] ) {"  I think, that's a problem in relation with my first.

Answer (score 2):

You are most likely running into the "unfiltered for/in" problem. IE, when iterating for/in loops, runs across all properties and methods of an object to include those which it got from the prototype. This leads to several issues as your code usually assumes it is only going to encounter a certain kind of property. The most generic method of filtering for/in is shown below where I ensure that the current element is actually a property of the object being iterated and not just something which was inherited. You can get much more specific in such a check by ensuring that the current property is exactly the type, instance, or value you expect.

```
Object.prototype.between = function( value )
{
    var value = parseFloat(value);
    for (key in this) {         
        if( Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call( key, this ) ) {
            var el = this[key];
            var v = key.split('-');         

            var min = parseFloat(v[0]);
            var max = parseFloat(v[1]);

            if (value >= min && value < max) { return el; }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

As noted in the comments, there are other things you could do to your code to make it more solid and less error prone.  You should start making a habit of running all your code through http://www.jshint.com

Comment: i think this "Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call( key, this )" should be this.hasOwnProperty(key). Correct me if iam wrong!!

Comment: Both will work, however the one I used is recommended by Douglas Crockford when he discusses for/in filtering. The reasoning he gave makes sense, but I cannot remember exactly what he said at the moment. Also, the version I used will work for *any* for/in loop--no matter what you're iterating.

Comment: @JAAulde I think the Object.prototyp.hasOwnProperty is better to use to make sure the the object in question hasn't overriden the hasOwnProperty function

Comment: @Matt - I removed your edit to my answer.  I purposely did not address anything other than the direct issue at hand, and recommended he LINT his code for the rest. Moreover, if I were to have corrected the lack of `var` declaration, it would have been above the `for` as I personally only use one `var` statement per function.

Comment: @JAAulde: I don't see anything wrong with promoting better programming in an answer, but fair enough; it's your answer :P

Comment: The Crockford talk to which I refered is in six parts. The first five are aggregated here: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/crockford-on-javascript-the-complete-series/ and the sixth is at http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/theater/video.php?v=crockford-loopage . It's a long watch, but very interesting and well worth it.

Comment: @Matt - I know what you're saying, but I try to specifically address the error at hand with my initial answer, and then sometimes I rewrite the entire code sample and add it below my answer as an example of how I'd fix it up. Also, while your adjustment is better than what the OP posted, I don't find it to be the best practice either. (Sorry if I sound like an ass for that.)